# djangorestframework-gis order by distance to point

Tags: django-rest-framework, gis, geodjango

In [`djangorestframework-gis`](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis), there exists the [`DistanceToPointFilter`](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis#distancetopointfilter) which returns results within a certain distance from a given point. How can I then have the results ordered by distance from that point, without repeating any distance calculations?

This is what my DRF view currently looks like:

```
class PlaceList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Place.objects.filter(active=True)
    serializer_class = ListSerializer
    distance_filter_field = 'address.geometry'
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, DistanceToPointFilter)
    filter_class = PlaceFilter
    ordering_fields = ('area', 'year_completed')
```

Comment: I don't think the distance to point filter supports ordering the data, so you probably need to write a custom solution for this, or extend the filter itself to allow ordering, see https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis/blob/d56068295cb6a2bf19d12de99fee6d63f1eec985/rest_framework_gis/filters.py#L109

Comment: well, you probably will need a custom endpoint for that. Without a point information to compare your locations with, it's impossible to know the distance.